# Why getter triggers sometimes in template?

Tags: angular

There is a component in which the children are activated by the ngIf condition.

Wrote a getter to check how many times it jerks:

```
{{test}}
<app-comp1 * ngIf = "one"> </app-comp1>
<app-comp2 * ngIf = "two"> </app-comp2>
```

Getter:

```
   get test () {
     console.log ('1')
     return '1'
   }
```

When switching tabs - changing one, two variables - the getter is called 4 times.

What could be the reason?
The component has `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

Comment: Are tabs located in component that has `onPush`?, and how are you changing variables?

Change detection happens in `onPush` component because an event is triggered from `onPush` component which makes him "dirty" and it should be checked for changes

Comment: Yes, tabs is inside parent component it is just div elements with click event,by click I change variable to true/false

Comment: For example I toggle tab by: `tab() {
    this.one = !this.one;
}`

<div (click)="tab()">Show tab one</div>

Comment: Every time you click a change detection will run, and execute your getter

Comment: Why if I have onPush, it should executed only when input changes. And why it calls four time instead one

Comment: Not only when input changes but also when event was triggered from `onPush` component. Such as click, keyup etc, or you have called `markForCheck`

Comment: How to optimize it? To call only one when event happens

Comment: Is it bad idea to switch a lot of components by ngif?

Comment: It depends, but in overall it is okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OnPush there are 3 ways change detection gets triggered:

- An @Input of your component change (compared with ===)
- An event you    subscribed to with () in template or @HostListener in
  code happens
- Change detection is manually triggered (i.e with ChangeDetectorRef)

So in your case even if component is under `onPush` strategy, but event occurs in that component, it will be checked for changes

Comment: What if I move this part to another child compoent,  I mean if event happens in parent component will it effect to child component rendering?

Comment: If they have Default strategy - yes. If OnPush you already know the rules